# What happens to manual Upstart services on shut down?

Tags: startup, shutdown, services, upstart

If using the `manual` keyword in an init or override Upstart script, it is not clear whether the services shut down process will be initiated or it will just be killed on shut down.

For instance, will MySQLs default timeout be extended (giving it enough time to flush buffers, as specified in the init script) when the manual override is used? If not, would it be preferable to use a `start on never` setting, or do manually started services need to also be manually shut down?

The [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#manual) has little to say on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must have overlooked something as this is really clear in the link you provided:

> #### [5.2.1   Observations](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#observations)
>
> There are some important points related to system shutdown:
>
> [...]
>
> - Upstart never stops a job with no `stop on` condition.
>
> [...]
>
> #### [5.2.2   Shutdown Process](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#shutdown-process)
>
> [...]
>
> One of the scripts run is `/etc/init.d/sendsigs`.
>
> This script will kill any remaining processes not already stopped (including Upstart processes).

In this `sendsigs` script it's explained:

> Upstart has a method to set a kill timeout and so the job author may
>   want us to wait longer than 10 seconds (as in the case of  mysql).
>   (LP: #688541)
>
> We will wait up to 300 seconds for any jobs in stop/killed state.  Any
>   kill timeout higher than that will be overridden by the need  to
>   shutdown. NOTE the re-use of seq from above, since we already  waited
>   up to 10 seconds for them.

Answer (score 3):

Manual stanza refers to starting a job. See [Upstart Technical Overview: Manual stanza](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/TechnicalOverviewUpstart#Manual_stanza). Therefore, a stop stanza defined in the overridden configuration file will be fully respected.

In the case of the MySQL server it is more important to define/override [pre-start](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-start), [post-start](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#post-start) and [kill timeout](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#kill-timeout) stanzas. For details examine default mysql.conf

```
cat /etc/init/mysql.conf
```

Blog entry [Ubuntu Upstart for automatic MySQL start and stop](http://karlssonondatabases.blogspot.com/2010/12/ubunto-upstart-for-automatic-mysql.html) has several ideas on how to improve default MySQL Upstart configuration file.